# Overloading Operator < for std::set

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a struct called Dist,

```cpp
struct Dist {
    Point firstPoint, secondPoint;
    double value;
};

struct distCompare {
    bool operator()(const Dist& x, const Dist& y) const {
        return x.value < y.value;
    }
};
```

and I have a set to store this Object.

```
std::set<Dist, distCompare> distList;
```

Two Dists like x and y are equal if `x.firstPoint==y.firstPoint and x.secondPoint==y.secondPoint` 
and since `distCompare` compares the value of two Dists, I cant use `set::find` like this:

```cpp
for (auto q:input) {
    Dist tempDist; tempDist.firstPoint = p; tempDist.secondPoint = q;
    auto it = distList.find(tempDist);
    if (it != distList.end()) { //'it' is always distList.end() 
        distList.erase(it); 
    }
}
```

my Point class looks like this:

```cpp
class Point {
public:
    Point(double a, double b){ x = a; y = b; }
    Point(){}
    double getX() const { return x; }
    double getY() const { return y; }
    void setX(double item){ x = item; }
    void setY(double item){ y = item; }

private:
    double x, y;
};
```

how can I overload operator < so that I can use `set::find` to find equal Dists?

Comment: `std::set<T, Cmp>::find` will always use `Cmp` to decide equivalence (rather than equality), so if you don't want it to find based on `distCompare` ... don't use `distCompare` in the set.

Comment: Is the Dist::value the distance between those points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::set<T, Cmp>::find` does a binary search, relying on the fact that the elements are ordered, and will always use `Cmp` to decide equivalence (which is not the same as than equality), so if you don't want it to find based on `distCompare` ... then don't use `distCompare` in the set!

Since the ordering defined by `distCompare` is completely unrelated to your definition of equality for `Dist` objects, there is no way to perform a fast binary search using the `distCompare` ordering to find objects that are considered equal by an entirely different function. You could have two elements that are "equal" according to your definition of equality, but are ordered at opposite ends of the set according to the ordering defined by `distCompare`.

Your options are:

- change the comparison function for the set, so that items that compare equal also compare equivalent using the comparison function.
- replace the set with a multi-index container, such as Boost.MultiIndex.
- perform a linear search through the set

Comment: Thank you, I think performing a linear search through the set is the best option for me.

Comment: `auto it = std::find(std::begin(distList), std::end(distList), tempDist);`

Comment: You should also be aware that although `std::set` stores unique elements, that only means unique _according to the comparison function_. There could be two elements that have equal  `firstPoint` and `secondPoint` members but different `value` members.